# Libgdx dim screen with glClearColor

Tags: java, android, libgdx, opengl-2.0

I simply want to draw background, overlay it with 0.5f transparent black color to dim it and render on top of that a pause menu.

I have tried:

```
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0.5f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

and nothing is working. I also couldn't find any solution online. My other option is to overlay a black sprite, but I don't want to do that. Is there anyway to paint it over with GL?

Comment: Do you mean you want the background (such as the phone's wallpaper) to show through behind the OpenGL stuff? Or are you just trying to obscure your other objects in the game while it's paused? If that's the case, you should not clear the screen...you should draw a rectangle over everything. It's not clear what you're trying to do. Your above code clears the OpenGL surface and makes it all black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would draw a transparent rectangle

```
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.5f));
    shapeRenderer.rect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    shapeRenderer.end();
    Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Your only solution is overlay a black sprite. Is the most efficient, and practice.

According to the documentation:

```
Alpha function, blend function, logical operation, stenciling, 
texture mapping, and depth-buffering are ignored by glClear.

glClear takes a single argument that is the bitwise OR of several
values indicating which buffer is to be cleared.

The values are as follows:

GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT
    Indicates the buffers currently enabled for color writing.
```

There can't be more colors "under" after running a glClear